# Getting the width of a row, which has elements overflowing

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

[image]

I'd like to make a slider, in which there are dynamic number of boxes. 
The row doesn't have an explicit width, its in a container, which has a width:100% and paddingHorizontal. 
I'd like to get the width of the row, but with onLayout it only gives me back the container width. 
The problem is, there can be boxes flowing out of the row, like on the picture and I'd like to get the row width, considering all the boxes, even those are not in the screen. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: There are already good slider modules, why should you make them?

Comment: @hongdevelop my job requires to minimize the amount of external components used, so I am trying to write modules on my own as much as I can

Comment: what do you want to do with the row's width ?

Comment: @RomainLavalle I'd like to animate the row's position by changing its left position. I need the width because I want to compare the width with the current left, so the row's right border wont be inner than the container's right border

Comment: Why not use a horizontal `ScrollView`?